# How do I get visual themes on Win32 dialogs generated from resource files?

Tags: c++, windows, resources, dialog

I've got a dialog defined in a resource file. However, it's using the Windows 95 style buttons and such. How do I use visual themes (i.e. those added in XP and later) for these controls?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to embed a manifest file into the executable that tells Windows you want the version of the controls that have themes enabled ([there's MSDN documentation specifically for this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx)). This is really for compatibility reasons because [some people really like to write programs that mess around with the internal data structures of other programs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/29/7294949.aspx).

In Visual C++, probably the easiest way to do this is via a `#pragma`:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"" \
    "type='win32' " \
    "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' " \
    "version='6.0.0.0' " \
    "processorArchitecture='*' "  \
    "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' " \
    "language='*'\"")
```

This causes the linker to add something like this to the generated manifest file:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

You also need to call [`InitCommonControlsEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775697.aspx) to register the appropriate control classes, or the dialog box won't appear.

As Mark Ransom has mentioned in the comments below, [Windows 2000 ignores theming manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563660.aspx), so this should still work in Windows 2000, Windows XP and later. Also, some frameworks like MFC define the `#pragma` and performs the initialization for you.

Comment: Does adding the dependency on the "6.0.0.0" version in the manifest break running on Windows 2000?

Comment: I find that this is all done for me when I create a new MFC project. The `#pragma` are in `stdafx.h` and the `InitCommonControlsEx` is in `InitInstance`.

Comment: Manifests are ignored by Windows 2000, so all you have to do is make the proper initialization calls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Mark: I'm not using MFC (hence I was confused).

Comment: Is this still needed under Windows 10 which doesn't have the old style?